# Apache Camel: <onException> block doesn't work after upgrading to camel 2.16.1

Tags: apache-camel

I have the onException block below that worked before I upgraded to from camel 2.14 to camel 2.16.1. Before the update, I would get my error caught and printed in the log - "Error posting to MR". After I upgraded to camel 2.16.1, I still get my error in the log, but now, always, my handled error is followed by another timestamp with what appears to be camel default error handler for the error I think I already handled. It looks like this:

```
"2016-01-26 15:07:09,571 [Camel (mrPostContext) thread #56 - JmsConsumer[mrPost]] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId"....
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, I tried using java.lang.Throwable instead of java.lang.Exception but so far had no luck. Haven't found anything helpful in documentation yet. As I'm far from being good with camel, I will much appreciate some help.

```
    <route id="mrPost">
        <from uri="activemq:mrPost?concurrentConsumers=8" />
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="1000"/>
            <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>

            <to uri="activemq:mr-post-fail" />

            <log loggingLevel="ERROR" message="Error posting to MR body:${out.body} exception message: ${exception.message} body:${exception.responseBody}" />  
        </onException> 

        <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
           <constant>PUT</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <recipientList>
            <simple>{{mr.source}}/${headers.id}</simple>
        </recipientList>

    </route>
```

Comment: Also tried removing trace attribute from context and adding context level onException block, but made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much cleaner solution in case someone is looking for it:

```
<errorHandler id="loggingErrorHandler" type="LoggingErrorHandler" logName="LoggingErrorHandler" level="OFF"/>
<camelContext id="mrPostContext" trace="false" errorHandlerRef="loggingErrorHandler" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that camel is failing where it puts the message on to the error queue **mr-post-fail** and is throwing an exception when doing so, hence your exception is propogating to the DefaultExceptionHandler. Since the logging is after the put queue call it is not working as you expected.

If not the case can you give the whole line of the error thats being printed.

```
  "2016-01-26 15:07:09,571 [Camel (mrPostContext) thread #56 - JmsConsumer[mrPost]] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId"..
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. I also posted on Camel forum, one of the moderator responded that there are settings to turn the default handler off, but he didn't say what settings. Others also left comments about not knowing if this is a camel bug: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/onException-block-in-camel-2-16-1-td5777019.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the defaultErrorHandler to collapse with these 2 adjustments:

```
 - set  messageHistory="false"  on CONTEXT
 - set  logStackTrace="false" for onException block, like this:
 <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="1000" logStackTrace="false" />
```

The timestamp with default error handler still shows up, but much easier on the eye, it looks like this:

```
2016-02-01 11:26:27,792 [Camel (mrPostContext) thread #262 - JmsConsumer[mrPost]] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-qn7nwscms01-com-44939-1454025367155-1569-4 on ExchangeId: ID-qn7nwscms01-com-44939-1454025367155-1569-5). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 3 caught: org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://mr.cloud.dig.com/api/contents/news/30939510 with statusCode: 409. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Pipeline[[Channel[SetHeader(CamelExceptionCaught, Simple: Headers: ${headers}  Message: ${exception.message}  Body: ${exception.responseBody})], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[activemq://mr-post-fail])], Channel[choice{when Filter[if: Simple: ${exception.message} not contains "statusCode: 409" do: Pipeline[[Channel[SetHeader(Content-Type, text/plain)], Channel[SetHeader(to, Simple: lw@ac.com)], Channel[SetHeader(subject, Simple: Error posting to MR)], Channel[SetBody(Simple: ${header.CamelExceptionCaught})]]]]}], Channel[Log(mrPost)[Error posting to MR ID: ${headers.contentId}, type:${headers.cmsContentType}, modified:${headers.lastModifiedDate}, getTime:${headers.lastModifiedGetTime}]], Channel[Log(merlinPost)[Error posting to MR body:${out.body} exception message: ${exception.message} body:${exception.responseBody}]]]]]
```

I hope there is a way to turn it off completely.
I also tried using defaultErrorHandler setup:

```
<errorHandler id="defaultErrorHandler" type="DefaultErrorHandler">
    <redeliveryPolicy  logStackTrace="false"/>
</errorHandler>
```

but it makes no impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the example in this page: http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

```
<!-- setup our error handler as the deal letter channel -->
<bean id="errorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:mr-post-fail"/>
</bean>

<!-- this is the camel context where we define the routes -->
<!-- define our error handler as a global error handler -->
<camelContext errorHandlerRef="errorHandler" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

  <route>
    <!-- the route -->
    <from uri="activemq:mrPost?concurrentConsumers=8" />
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
           <constant>PUT</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <recipientList>
        <simple>{{mr.source}}/${headers.id}</simple>
    </recipientList>
  </route>

</camelContext>
```

Or, set in rote, to the error handle work only with an specific route

```
<route errorHandlerRef="errorHandler">
...
</route>
```

And remove from camelContext